# Abort trap 6 when adding an extension to an external dependency

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, unit-testing

I am attempting to add an extension to a dependency for testing purposes. The dependency is a class marked as final and I would like to make a protocol that mimics the interface so I can swap the real implementation out for a mock object in my tests. I'm currently getting an abort trap 6 error when building my tests if the extension is included in my project. Without the extension, the project builds without error, but I am unable to pass my dependency as the protocol which prevents me from swapping it for a mock object in my tests. Because the class is marked final, I can't subclass the object to add my protocol to it.

I have added 3 objects to allow this behavior:

**RealmProtocol.swift**: This is a protocol mimicking the public interface of the Realm object (my external dependency, but this is not specific to Realm).

```
import RealmSwift

protocol RealmProtocol {
    func add(_ object: Object, update: Bool)
    func beginWrite()
    func commitWrite(withoutNotifying tokens: [NotificationToken]) throws
    func object<Element: Object, KeyType>(ofType type: Element.Type, forPrimaryKey key: KeyType) -> Element?
    func objects<Element: Object>(_ type: Element.Type) -> Results<Element>
}
```

**MockRealm.swift**: This is my mock object for Realm.swift. In production, the Realm object will be used, in my tests, it will be swapped with MockRealm so I can verify that the correct method is getting called at the correct time.

```
import Foundation
import RealmSwift

@testable import RealmObjectMocking

class MockRealm: RealmProtocol {
    var addCalled = false
    var beginWriteCalled = false
    var commitWriteCalled = false
    var objectCalled = false
    var objectsCalled = false

    var objectReturn: Any?

    func add(_ object: Object, update: Bool) {
        addCalled = true
    }

    func beginWrite() {
        beginWriteCalled = true
    }

    func commitWrite(withoutNotifying tokens: [NotificationToken]) throws {
        commitWriteCalled = true
    }

    func object<Element: Object, KeyType>(ofType type: Element.Type, forPrimaryKey key: KeyType) -> Element? {
        objectCalled = true
        let object = objectReturn as? Element
        return object
    }

    func objects<Element: Object>(_ type: Element.Type) -> Results<Element> {
        objectsCalled = true
        let realm = try! Realm()
        return realm.objects(type)
    }
}
```

**Realm.swift**: This is the extension on the Realm object to make it conform to my protocol. Without this file in the project, it builds without error. With this included, I get abort trap 6. The implementation is empty since my protocol is matching the existing public methods on the Realm object.

```
import RealmSwift

extension Realm: RealmProtocol {}
```

I'm not sure if this is an issue with extending a class that is marked final or if I'm getting some sort of circular dependency here, or maybe another issue altogether. Many posts have recommended turning off optimization to get past this error, but that has not helped. Additionally, opening the MockRealm.swift file when the class extension is included in the project causes the editor to crash. Because of that, I have also filed a Radar for this issue.

Here is a link to a sample project that shows the issue. The code in the sample app is identical to the code above: https://github.com/skladek/RealmObjectMocking

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to be an Xcode bug rather than an implementation issue. An Apple dev told me that this is fixed in Xcode10-Beta 1. I have tested and confirmed. Since my product will launch after Xcode 10 and iOS 12 are released, I'm content with leaving as is.